# Samsung GT-I5510 custom recovery

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, device-firmware

I was looking around for installing a custom recovery and then a custom firmware on my old phone, but I couldn't any links that were still available and not adware ridden, can anyone give me some advice on where to search?

Comment: See: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2183920) is custom cwm touch recovery for your Samsung GT-I5510 phone and [Here](http://samsunggti5510.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_ROMS) is list of custom firmware for your phone

Please refer all the instruction/steps in provided link carefully before flashing anything

Comment: Just going to add my usual: Make a [tag:nandroid] backup before flashing anything!

Comment: I already found this, but for flashing you need Odin Multidownloader 4.34 for it, I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Google it man http://www.androidgyan.com/2011/12/download-odin-multi-downloader-samsung.html

Comment: all these links are to megaupload which is dead

Comment: http://uploaded.net/file/63ckebud